# New hidesBarsOnSwipe feature with UIWebView makes a visual mistake

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

I have an UIViewController with an UIWebView inside. I have enabled the navigationController hidesBarsOnSwipe flag so that when I scroll up the content of the UIWebView, the navigation bar gets hidden. This feature works fine in the most of cases but with the Web pages who have their own header, the application makes a mistake. You can see an example below:

This is the Web Page with the navigation bar visible:

[image: This is the Web Page with the navigation bar visible]

And this how it looks when I scroll up the UIWebView and the navigation bar disappears:

[image: And this is the aspect when I scroll up the UIWebView and the navigation bar disappears]

The Web page's header does not place just below the status bar. You can see another example in this picture:

[image: You can see another example in this picture]

Is this an iOS bug or I am doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you need to use `barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer` to listen to the bar visibility modification and when you detect it, reload the website content or at least poke the webView to re-render some content. I hade similar issues with normal UITableView, having to modify the size myself after UINavigationBar is hidden.